# How to specify which class is being referred to: reference to [method] is ambiguous..." [jxl]

Tags: java, jxl

I'm writing a program using jxl: a Java API that allows you to read, write and modify Excel spreadsheets (http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/). The following code creates a new Number cell that contains a number according to three parameters: the column number, row number and value of the number.

```
//creates the cell
Number number = new Number(columnNum,rowNum, value);
//adds the cell to the Excel sheet
sheet.addCell(number);
```

However, "Number" is shared by both the jxl.write.Number and java.lang.Number classes, so the program doesn't know which one I'm referencing. I'm given this error:

reference to Number is ambiguous, both class jxl.write.Number in jxl.write and class java.lang.Number in java.lang match.

How would I go about fixing this? Could I specify which class I'm referencing somehow? Is it possible to change the name of one of the classes/methods so they're unique and can be referenced separately?

Answer (score 1):

Specify complete package -

Ex -

```
jxl.write.Number number = new jxl.write.Number(columnNum,rowNum, value);
//adds the cell to the Excel sheet
sheet.addCell(number);
```